# sharp inequalities for $(x+y)^{a}$ and $(x+y+z)^{a}$ for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $a \in (1,2).$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $a\in (1,2).$ Then it is well known that
$$(x+y+z)^{a} \leq C ( x^a + y^a + z^a)$$
for some constant $C>0.$ I am interested in inequalities that involve cross-terms, by which I mean expressions of the term $x^{a_1}y^{a_2}z^{a_2}$ for $0\leq a_1,a_2,a_3$ (so for instance $x^{a-1}y$ could be a cross term). Any reference to such inequalities will be much appreciated.

Comment: minor comment - did you mean $1-a\ge0$, or else how does it fit into $a_i\ge 0$? Are you asking if you can make a "nontrivial" term with cross terms that sits between LHS and RHS?

Comment: @CalvinKhor thank you for your comment. you are right, I fixed the question

Comment: now that $a\in(1,2)$ you can e.g. write $$(x+y+z)^a = (x+y+z)^{a-1}(x+y+z) \le (x^{a-1} + y^{a-1} + z^{a-1})(x+y+z).$$ However I'm not sure exactly what could count as an "Answer" for your question, maybe try to cleanly formulate something you're after?

Comment: What is the definition of "cross-term"? Why is the term $x^{a_1}y^{a_2}z^{a_3}$ here?

Comment: You could check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality which gives a general account on the generalized mean inequality which you are using here. Particularly, you can use any factorization  $\alpha = \prod_{k=1}^n \alpha_k$ to come up with cross-terms.

Comment: @NN2 for instance if we consider the expansion of $(x+y)^2$ then the term 2xy would be a cross term